# What is the C# extension methods equivalent for this Linq query?

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, extension-methods

In **[this example:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336754.aspx#simple1)**

```
public void Linq40()
{
    int[] numbers = { 5, 4, 1, 3, 9, 8, 6, 7, 2, 0 };

    var numberGroups =
        from n in numbers
        group n by n % 5 into g
        select new { Remainder = g.Key, Numbers = g };

    foreach (var g in numberGroups)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Numbers with a remainder of {0} when divided by 5:",
            g.Remainder);

        foreach (var n in g.Numbers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(n);
        }
    }
}
```

What is the pure c# equivalent?  I get this...

```
var numberGroups = numbers.GroupBy(n => n % 5)...
```

but the `into` clause is a bit of a mystery, and I can't figure out how to get the `Key` from the `Select`.

Comment: I think you mean the way to do it with "Extension Methods"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501.aspx) returns an `IEnumerable<T>` of [`<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344977.aspx).  With this, you can do a second Select operation, which returns values exactly like above:

```
var numberGroups = numbers.GroupBy(n => n % 5)
                          .Select(g => new { Remainder = g.Key, Numbers = g });
```

Answer (score 8):

```
numbers.GroupBy(n => n % 5).Select(g => new { Remainder = g.Key, Numbers = g });
```